# Brainfuck interpreter in c printing trouble

Tags: c, printing, interpreter, brainfuck

I'm trying to code a very simple brainfuck interpreter in C, and I run into problems while trying to outprint certain characters by what I understand.

This is all my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bla(char tabukaz[30000], int ukaz, int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    int index = ukaz;
    while (sum > -1) {
        index -= num;
        if (tabukaz[index] == ']')
          sum += num;
        else if (tabukaz[index] == '[')
          sum -= num;
    }   
    return index;
}

int main () {
    int tab[30000];
    int tabukaz[30000];
    int c; 
    int i = 0; int ukaz = 0;
    unsigned char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        tab[i] = 0;
        tabukaz[i] = 0;
    }
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        ch = (unsigned char)c;
        if (ch == '>' || ch == '<' || ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '.' || ch == '[' || ch == ']')
        {
            tabukaz[ukaz] = ch;
        }

        switch (ch) {
            case '>': i++; break;
            case '<': i--; break;
            case '+': tab[i]++;break;
            case '-': tab[i]--; break;
            case '.': putchar(tab[i]); break;
            case '[':
                if (tab[i]==0) {
                    ukaz = bla(tabukaz, ukaz, -1);
                }
                break;
            case ']':
                if (tab[i]!=0) {
                    ukaz = bla(tabukaz, ukaz, 1);
                }    
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        ukaz++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the input in question (I tried to avoid the other text in the actual input (keep in mind everything down here is part of the input, even the unnecessary text) We were provided with a make file which will write the output into a text file, and compare it to a predefined text, the problem is my text file comes out as a binary file and I cant figure out why. The problem may be hidden in how I handle `[` and `]` as I didn't have that problem in the earlier tests without them

```
+++++ +++++             initialize counter (cell #0) to 10
[                       use loop to set 70/100/30/10
    > +++++ ++              add  7 to cell #1
    > +++++ +++++           add 10 to cell #2
    > +++                   add  3 to cell #3
    > +                     add  1 to cell #4
<<<< -                  decrement counter (cell #0)
]
> ++ .                  print 'H'
> + .                   print 'e'
+++++ ++ .              print 'l'
.                       print 'l'
+++ .                   print 'o'
> ++ .                  print ' '
<< +++++ +++++ +++++ .  print 'W'
> .                     print 'o'
+++ .                   print 'r'
----- - .               print 'l'
----- --- .             print 'd'
> + .                   print '!'
> .                     print '\n'
```

As a suggestion made by somebody I did this:

```
while ((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
    ch = (unsigned char)c;
    if (ch == '>' || ch == '<' || ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '.' || ch == '[' || ch == ']')
    {
        tabukaz[ukaz]=ch;
        stukaz++;
    }
}

while (stukaz>0) {
    switch (tabukaz[ukaz]) {
        case '>': i++; break;
        case '<': i--; break;
        case '+': if(tab[i]==255) tab[i] = 0;
                  else tab[i]++;
                  break;
        case '-': if (tab[i]==0) tab[i] = 255;
                  else tab[i]--;
                  break;
        case '.': printf ("%c", tab[i]); break;
        case '[':
            if (tab[i]==0) {
                ukaz = bla(tabukaz, ukaz, -1);
            }
            break;
        case ']':
            if (tab[i]!=0) {
                ukaz = bla(tabukaz, ukaz, 1);
            }    
            break;
        default: break;
    }
    stukaz--;
    ukaz++;
 }
```

However the problem now extends to the tests before that, as it even outputs those as binary files, I'm thinking there's something wrong with the `[` and `]` code and thus it doesn't increment the fields properly printing unwanted characters, how this extended to tests without them only when putting another loop around it I have no idea.

EDIT: the problem with the above loop is not the while loop not going trough, the problem is that it will never get into the switch, any solution to that?

Comment: Is your question why your output is binary? I am slightly confused : )

In what environment are you compiling and executing this?

Comment: I guess you mean that non-printable (or funny) characters are written to the screen. In that case, why not replace `putchar(x)` with `printf("%d\n", x)` to see the actual value of these characters. This might help you to find the bug.

Comment: Your register poiter `i` will have the value 30,000 after the initialisation loops have been carried out. That's one index beyond your array.

Comment: You can't read the program from stdin like you do: When you hit a closing bracket `]`, you might have to go backwards, which means `fseek`ing stdin, which usually isn't possible. A better idea would be to read the program into `tabukaz` first and then work on the array, where you can go forwards and backwards as you like.

Comment: I have tried that Oehm, but the problem i have now is, i put counter in where i read into tabukaz, and then i put a while loop around it decrementing the number each time i go over it, the problem i run into is that the loop will break after 1 operation, i will update what i did in a sec

Comment: Ive managed to make something, the problem i dont get is why will it never jump into the switch

Comment: Where do I put the edited code in the original program?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Absolutely not. Please read Code Review's on-topic guidelines.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes No, this does not belong on Code Review. Please read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers). Important thing to keep in mind: Questions containing the word "problem" does not belong on Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

The test is wrong while scanning for a matching bracket.

```
 while (sum > -1) {
        index -= num;
        if (tabukaz[index] == ']')
          sum += num;
        else if (tabukaz[index] == '[')
          sum -= num;
    }
```

You set `num` to 1 for a backwards scan, but to -1 for a forward scan.

```
    case '[':
        if (tab[i]==0) {
            ukaz = bla(tabukaz, ukaz, -1);
        }
        break;
    case ']':
        if (tab[i]!=0) {
            ukaz = bla(tabukaz, ukaz, 1);
        }    
        break;
```

So the test should be `(sum != 0)` so it stops when the brackets are balanced from either direction. Of course, `sum` is initialized to 0, so I recommend a `do { ... } while();` loop so the test is at the end.

Also, remember that you're incrementing the instruction pointer at the end of the loop.

```
        ukaz++;
```

So you may want to set the pointer to `bla(...) - 1`, so the increment puts the pointer in the correct place.

---

You might also like to look at [my own brainfuck interpreter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25934/brainfuck-interpreter-in-c), which is very similar to yours. One of my reviewers there gives an excellent explanation of optimizing the loop execution with a jump table.